# JOOQ code generation giving error The <generator/> tag is mandatory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, vert.x, jooq

I am trying to use JOOQ with vertx with latest version 4.0.0. I want to generate my Daos and table through gradle. Following is my build.gradle code

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        vertx_jooq_version = '4.0.0'
        postgresql_version = '42.2.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.github.jklingsporn:vertx-jooq-generate:$vertx_jooq_version"
        classpath "org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgresql_version"
    }
}

import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import org.jooq.util.GenerationTool

import javax.xml.bind.JAXB

group 'your group id'
version 'your project version'

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile "io.github.jklingsporn:vertx-jooq-classic:$vertx_jooq_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

task jooqGenerate {
    doLast() {
        def writer = new StringWriter()
        new MarkupBuilder(writer)
                .configuration('xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.10.0.xsd') {
            jdbc {
                driver('org.postgresql.Driver')
                url('jdbc:postgresql://IP:PORT/DATABASE')
                user('YOUR_USER')
                password('YOUR_PASSWORD')
            }
            generator {
                name('io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.generate.classic.ClassicJDBCVertxGenerator')
                database {
                    name('org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase')
                    include('.*')
                    excludes('schema_version')
                    inputSchema('public')
                    includeTables(true)
                    includeRoutines(true)
                    includePackages(false)
                    includeUDTs(true)
                    includeSequences(true)
                }
                generate([:]) {
                    deprecated(false)
                    records(false)
                    interfaces(true)
                    fluentSetters(true)
                    pojos(true)
                    daos(true)
                }
                target() {
                    packageName('io.one.sys.db')
                    directory("$projectDir/src/main/java")
                }
                strategy {
                    name('io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.generate.VertxGeneratorStrategy')
                }
            }
        }
        GenerationTool.generate(
                JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(writer.toString()), org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration.class)
        )
    }
}
```

which is taken from the github link https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/tree/master/vertx-jooq-classic-jdbc

but when I run commmand `./gradlew jooqGenerate` to generate code, it is giving error : 
`The <generator/> tag is mandatory. For details, see http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd`

I checked `org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool` in JOOQ codegen library. following is the code

```
 org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Generator g = configuration.getGenerator();
            if (g == null)
                throw new GeneratorException("The <generator/> tag is mandatory. For details, see " + Constants.NS_CODEGEN);
```

link : https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-codegen/src/main/java/org/jooq/codegen/GenerationTool.java

Seems like problem in configuration.getGenerator();

And following is the link of org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Generator file
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-meta/src/main/java/org/jooq/meta/jaxb/Generator.java

I see following methods

```
public Generator withGenerate(Generate value) {
        setGenerate(value);
        return this;
    }

public void setGenerate(Generate value) {
        this.generate = value;
    }
```

I cant dig it more who should call withGenerate() method to create Generator object.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here or is there any problem with jklingsporn library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it.
I had to update url http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.10.0.xsd to http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd As xsd has different version